# Weird Bug in TextView when starting the app

Tags: android, xml, textview

```
I just found out this weird bug
Im using Samsung Galaxy DUOS android 4.04
```

[image]

It only appears rarely just by opening the activity then pressing back button vice versa/continuously. The TextViews are just simple.

```
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paymentButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/payment_method"
            android:textColor="#868686" >
```

And the code is just the usual initializing and setting found in the Oncreate method
Setting the fonts is using the assets

I already found a hint where this bug came from but still unable to fix it. The hint
is I guess, because of the Fonts files. Any other way to clear this out ?

Comment: Is it working fine on other devices except Samsung Galaxy DUOS android 4.04?

Comment: Yeah .. I have galaxy nexus, samsung galaxy note 10.1, and other lenovo devices. None of it experience this kind of bug just samsung DUOS. please help

Comment: for the time being I just encountered this on samsung DUOS

Comment: So it is device specific issue not android. If you feel my above comment is helpful to you then you should upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

I used "samsung galaxy s duos s7562","Android version: 4.2.2" for testing my android app and the same type of error used to come up i.e. some textview used to display random characters(in my case not even english) in a similar scenario(back button press). However, the issue was resolved after 2-3 weeks (still not sure how).

You could try with a project clean for starters and follow with eclipse restart to see if it improves (i should have commented this but my reputation is too low to comment).

Comment: doesn't work, the bug is still exist .. weird :'( huhuhu

Comment: try wrapping that textview in relative layout(thats how i have my current code).

Answer (score 1):

It might a bug with the font files.